# Why does float left/right not work? Trying to align photo and text beside each other

Tags: html, css

I'm "converting" a responsive site from mobile to desktop and stumbled upon a problem. I can't figure out how to place photo and paragraph beside each other. I have provided the code for the mobile version and need help with the css for the desktop version.

Have tried float and other techniques, but the text mostly pushes down the photo.

This is my code: jsfiddle.net/coebadr0 
I want the header and paragraph to the right of the image

I expect something like this:

https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_layout_float2

```css
.marketing {
  background-color: black;
}

.marketing h2 {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: "Catamaran";
  color: white;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.marketing p {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: "Catamaran";
  color: white;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
}

.marketing img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<section class="marketing">
  <h2>Header</h2>
  <p>Text Text Text Text Text Text Text</p>
  <img src="img/marketing.jpg">
</section>
```

Comment: Put the image before the text and then float the image left or right. You say you tried float and it didn't work but you didn't demonstrate that in your code example.

Comment: I tried that, it kinda works, but when I try to add padding or margin to the text to align it vertically, it pushes the image too.

Comment: You need to show the code you're actually trying that isn't working. See [mcve]

Comment: and when I add the image before the text it messes up my mobile version (as I do mobile first)

Comment: here this explains better: https://jsfiddle.net/coebadr0/

I want the header and paragraph to the right of the image

Comment: Please do not add relevant information in comments, edit your question instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.marketing {
  background-color: black;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
}

.marketing h2 {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: "Catamaran";
  color: white;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.marketing p {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: "Catamaran";
  color: white;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
}

.marketing img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<section class="marketing">
  
   <img 
src="https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/976/cpsprodpb/27C9/production/_103158101_tha.jpg">
  
  <div class="text">
  <h2>Header</h2>
  <p>Text Text Text Text Text Text Text</p>
  </div>
 
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you follow the code of the w3 example? You aren't even floating your image? Your image is 100% width so it will take up the whole width what do you expect. Put this img before your `<p>` element.

```css
.marketing {
  background-color: black;
}

.marketing h2 {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: "Catamaran";
  color: white;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.marketing p {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: "Catamaran";
  color: white;
  font-weight: 300;
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
}

.marketing img {
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<section class="marketing">
  <h2>Header</h2>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"/>
  <p>Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
  Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
  Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
  Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
  Text Text Text Text Text Text Text</p>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Floats can in fact be used to achieve this text wrapped image you are looking for! Firstly, your image should be inside the `<p>` of text you want to wrap around it. Also, you've currently got your image set to `display: block;` and `width: 100%` which are making your image take up the full width of the container. I tweaked your code to match your desired layout:

```css
.marketing {
  background-color: black;
}

.marketing h2 {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: "Catamaran";
  color: white;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.marketing p {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: "Catamaran";
  color: white;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.marketing img {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<section class="marketing">
  <h2>Header</h2>
  <p><img src="https://placekitten.com/200/200">Text Text Text Text Text Text TextText Text Text Text Text Text TextText Text Text Text Text Text TextText Text Text Text Text Text Text</p>
</section>
```

**EDIT:** If you want to add padding between the text and image, you'll want to add it to the *image* instead of the paragraph, i.e.:

```
.marketing img {
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

actually you can try it with display: grid;

here is the code...

```css
.marketing {
  background-color: black;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
}

.marketing h2 {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: "Catamaran";
  color: white;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.marketing p {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: "Catamaran";
  color: white;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
}

.marketing img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<section class="marketing">
  
   <img src="img/marketing.jpg">
  
  <div class="text">
  <h2>Header</h2>
  <p>Text Text Text Text Text Text Text</p>
  </div>
 
</section>
```